# Exchange: use Port 110 for both POP3 & POP3/SSL?

Tags: exchange-2010, port, tls, pop3

On our Exchange 2010 POP3 is configured to only allow secure logon (TLS connection for authentification).

Now, the default port for "plain" POP3 is `110`, and for POP3 with SSL is `995`, hence with the given Exchange settings POP3 works ***only*** with SSL on `995`, currently.

Additionally, the Exchange server passes through some requests to another email server, who accepts "plain text" authentification. Therefore, port `110` works in this case.

**Suppose port `995` was blocked or can't be used for any reason, is it possible to configure Exchange to use *both* (unsecure POP3 and POP3 over SSL) on port `110`?**

I tried to do this, but it didn't work (*error "SSL authentification failed due to unexpected packet format" / "server doesn't accept encryption type"*):

```
TLS or unencrypted
- IPv4: 110
- IPv6: 110

SSL
- IPv4: 995
- IPv6: 955
- IPv4: 110 <-- I've added this
```

I feel I still don't fully understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Exchange already will use both [secured and unsecured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS) POP3 on port 110, as most modern POP3 servers do. Modern clients will use [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) for encryption on port 110, as your paste indicates (the "TLS or unencrypted" part). Nothing was wrong, why are you messing with it?

See section 4 of [RFC 2595](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2595) which explains the `STLS` method used to "upgrade" to a secure connection.

Comment: The client uses SSL, not TLS. And all I can tell is that POP3 with SSL on port 110 *didn't* work, only on port 995.

Comment: The client uses SSL if you tell it to, and indeed SSL on port 110 won't work. The client will use TLS too, assuming it's not ancient. The RFC I linked is from **1999** -- how old is your client?!?! Stop messing with it, nothing is wrong unless you keep breaking things.